# Dynamics 365 solution containing entities with two different publisher prefixes where one doesn't even exist

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I noticed in a solution my team inherited some time ago that entities have two different prefixes, however for one of the prefixes no publisher exists!

How would this be possible? I thought once there are objects created using a publisher that publisher cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix (free text) is always editable, probably someone edited the prefix for that particular Publisher afterwards.

> [image]

Comment: if they edit the prefix as suggest above, the entities for example won't update to the new prefix? They will just remain the same?

Comment: @MilesMorales for existing entities - no. it'll reflect for future customizations

Comment: Thanks I marked your question as an answer, I wish we could see the audit history of the publishers so we could know which one was updated.

Comment: For the future though I do see since Publishers is an entity, you can enable auditing on it.

Comment: @MilesMorales I see that, but the form is not reflecting the layout to show navigation "Audit history".. just enable the audit & have to query directly then for future references